# Reading HDFS and local files in Java

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I want to read file paths irrespective of whether they are HDFS or local. Currently, I pass the local paths with the prefix file:// and HDFS paths with the prefix hdfs:// and write some code as the following

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
FileSystem fileSystem = null;
if (filePath.startsWith("hdfs://")) {
  fileSystem = FileSystem.get(configuration);
} else if (filePath.startsWith("file://")) {
  fileSystem = FileSystem.getLocal(configuration).getRawFileSystem();
}
```

From here I use the API's of the FileSystem to read the file.

Can you please let me know if there is any other better way than this?

Comment: Why are you unhappy with your current method?

Comment: I am not unhappy per se. I want my method takes in an object of Path and I was wondering from the Path if there is any method that can tell me if this path belongs to a local or HDFS file system. I tried to do a toString of the Path and do the comparision above but it didnt work. I am having to to a toURI().toString() on the Path and do  this check.

Comment: I am not sure if I need to create a new post for this. I am sorry if I should have. Alternatively, my question is how do I find if a file path is HDFS or local if I have a Path and not a String. Would it be to do a toURI().toString() and do the check as I mentioned in my first post. Or to do a toURI() and check if the scheme. Thanks....

Answer (score 36):

Does this make sense,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.addResource(new Path("/hadoop/projects/hadoop-1.0.4/conf/core-site.xml"));
    conf.addResource(new Path("/hadoop/projects/hadoop-1.0.4/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Enter the file path...");
    String filePath = br.readLine();

    Path path = new Path(filePath);
    FileSystem fs = path.getFileSystem(conf);
    FSDataInputStream inputStream = fs.open(path);
    System.out.println(inputStream.available());
    fs.close();
}
```

You don't have to put that check if you go this way. Get the FileSystem directly from Path and then do whatever you feel like.

Comment: Hi Tariq, can the source local file be on edge node ? do you have full example of mapper class too ?

Answer (score 15):

You can get the `FileSystem` by the following way:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
Path path = new Path(stringPath);
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(path.toUri(), conf);
```

You do not need to judge if the path starts with `hdfs://` or `file://`. This API will do the work.

Comment: Tariq's solution does the same thing. Path.getFileSystem will invoke this FileSystem.get(URI, Configuration) method

Answer (score 1):

Please check the code snippet below that list files from HDFS path; namely the path string that starts with `hdfs://`. If you can provide Hadoop configuration and local path it will also list files from local file system; namely the path string that starts with `file://`.

```
    //helper method to get the list of files from the HDFS path
    public static List<String> listFilesFromHDFSPath(Configuration hadoopConfiguration, String hdfsPath,
                                                     boolean recursive)
    {
        //resulting list of files
        List<String> filePaths = new ArrayList<String>();
        FileSystem fs = null;

        //try-catch-finally all possible exceptions
        try
        {
            //get path from string and then the filesystem
            Path path = new Path(hdfsPath);  //throws IllegalArgumentException, all others will only throw IOException
            fs = path.getFileSystem(hadoopConfiguration);

            //resolve hdfsPath first to check whether the path exists => either a real directory or o real file
            //resolvePath() returns fully-qualified variant of the path
            path = fs.resolvePath(path);


            //if recursive approach is requested
            if (recursive)
            {
                //(heap issues with recursive approach) => using a queue
                Queue<Path> fileQueue = new LinkedList<Path>();

                //add the obtained path to the queue
                fileQueue.add(path);

                //while the fileQueue is not empty
                while (!fileQueue.isEmpty())
                {
                    //get the file path from queue
                    Path filePath = fileQueue.remove();

                    //filePath refers to a file
                    if (fs.isFile(filePath))
                    {
                        filePaths.add(filePath.toString());
                    }
                    else   //else filePath refers to a directory
                    {
                        //list paths in the directory and add to the queue
                        FileStatus[] fileStatuses = fs.listStatus(filePath);
                        for (FileStatus fileStatus : fileStatuses)
                        {
                            fileQueue.add(fileStatus.getPath());
                        } // for
                    } // else

                } // while

            } // if
            else        //non-recursive approach => no heap overhead
            {
                //if the given hdfsPath is actually directory
                if (fs.isDirectory(path))
                {
                    FileStatus[] fileStatuses = fs.listStatus(path);

                    //loop all file statuses
                    for (FileStatus fileStatus : fileStatuses)
                    {
                        //if the given status is a file, then update the resulting list
                        if (fileStatus.isFile())
                            filePaths.add(fileStatus.getPath().toString());
                    } // for
                } // if
                else        //it is a file then
                {
                    //return the one and only file path to the resulting list
                    filePaths.add(path.toString());
                } // else

            } // else

        } // try
        catch(Exception ex) //will catch all exception including IOException and IllegalArgumentException
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();

            //if some problem occurs return an empty array list
            return new ArrayList<String>();
        } //
        finally
        {
            //close filesystem; not more operations
            try
            {
                if(fs != null)
                    fs.close();
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } // catch

        } // finally


        //return the resulting list; list can be empty if given path is an empty directory without files and sub-directories
        return filePaths;
    } // listFilesFromHDFSPath
```

If you really want to work with java.io.File API then the following method will help you list files only from local file system; namely path string that starts with `file://`.

```
    //helper method to list files from the local path in the local file system
    public static List<String> listFilesFromLocalPath(String localPathString, boolean recursive)
    {
        //resulting list of files
        List<String> localFilePaths = new ArrayList<String>();

        //get the Java file instance from local path string
        File localPath = new File(localPathString);


        //this case is possible if the given localPathString does not exit => which means neither file nor a directory
        if(!localPath.exists())
        {
            System.err.println("\n" + localPathString + " is neither a file nor a directory; please provide correct local path");

            //return with empty list
            return new ArrayList<String>();
        } // if


        //at this point localPath does exist in the file system => either as a directory or a file


        //if recursive approach is requested
        if (recursive)
        {
            //recursive approach => using a queue
            Queue<File> fileQueue = new LinkedList<File>();

            //add the file in obtained path to the queue
            fileQueue.add(localPath);

            //while the fileQueue is not empty
            while (!fileQueue.isEmpty())
            {
                //get the file from queue
                File file = fileQueue.remove();

                //file instance refers to a file
                if (file.isFile())
                {
                    //update the list with file absolute path
                    localFilePaths.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
                } // if
                else   //else file instance refers to a directory
                {
                    //list files in the directory and add to the queue
                    File[] listedFiles = file.listFiles();
                    for (File listedFile : listedFiles)
                    {
                        fileQueue.add(listedFile);
                    } // for
                } // else

            } // while
        } // if
        else        //non-recursive approach
        {
            //if the given localPathString is actually a directory
            if (localPath.isDirectory())
            {
                File[] listedFiles = localPath.listFiles();

                //loop all listed files
                for (File listedFile : listedFiles)
                {
                    //if the given listedFile is actually a file, then update the resulting list
                    if (listedFile.isFile())
                        localFilePaths.add(listedFile.getAbsolutePath());
                } // for
            } // if
            else        //it is a file then
            {
                //return the one and only file absolute path to the resulting list
                localFilePaths.add(localPath.getAbsolutePath());
            } // else
        } // else


        //return the resulting list; list can be empty if given path is an empty directory without files and sub-directories
        return localFilePaths;
    } // listFilesFromLocalPath
```

Answer (score 0):

This work.

```
package com.leerhdfs;

//import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Progressable;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.URI;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class ReadWriteHDFSExample {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Path inFile = new Path(args[0]);
    String destinosrc = args[1];
    
    //InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(localsrc));
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    
    
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(destinosrc), conf);
    FSDataInputStream in = fs.open(inFile);
   
    
    //Progressable ir viendo aumento 10%, 20%, 30%
    OutputStream out = fs.create(new Path(destinosrc), new Progressable() {
        
        public void progress() {
            System.out.println("Leyendo y escribiendo...");
            
        }
    });
    
    IOUtils.copyBytes(in ,out, 4096, true);
       in.close();
  }

}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/late-answers/27917980)