# Reading HDFS through java API

Tags: java, hadoop

[possible duplicate]I am trying to read HDFS using java API. Using command line and Hadoop Url It's working fine 
but problem is reading while hdfs paths.I went through this [Reading HDFS and local files in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072543/reading-hdfs-and-local-files-in-java) but I am not able to find where i am wrong.

1)command line gives this result

```
  hduser@hduser-Satellite:~$ hadoop fs -ls 
  Found 3 items
  drwxr-xr-x   - hduser supergroup          0 2014-01-11 00:21 /user/hduser/In
  -rw-r--r--   1 hduser supergroup   37461150 2014-01-11 17:27 /user/hduser/loging.txt
  -rw-r--r--   3 hduser supergroup  112383446 2014-01-11 19:02 /user/hduser/loging1.txt
```

2)

```
       static {
               URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(new FsUrlStreamHandlerFactory());
          }
          InputStream in = null;
    try {
*********************This is working fine********************************
        in = new URL("hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hduser/loging.txt")
                .openStream();
*************************************************************************

*************************This is not working*****************************
       in = new URL("hdfs://localhost/user/hduser/loging.txt").openStream(); 

       It says:
       14/01/11 19:54:55 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server:
       localhost/127.0.0.1:8020. Already tried 0 time(s).
                              .
                              .
       14/01/11 19:55:04 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server:    
       localhost/127.0.0.1:8020. Already tried 9 time(s).
       Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Call to      
      localhost/127.0.0.1:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
**************************************************************************      

         IOUtils.copyBytes(in, System.out, 4096, false);

    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeStream(in);
    }
```

3)Giving Exception

```
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.addResource(new Path("/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml"));
    configuration.addResource(new Path("/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));

    FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.get(configuration);
    System.out.println(fileSystem.getHomeDirectory());
    Path path = new Path("/user/hduser/loging.txt");

    FSDataInputStream in = fileSystem.open(path);
    System.out.println(in);
    byte[] b = new byte[1024];
    int numBytes = 0;
    while ((numBytes = in.read(b)) > 0) {
        //processing
    }

    in.close();

    fileSystem.close();
Exception:
file:/home/hduser
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File /user/hduser/loging.txt does not exist.
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:361)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:245)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:125)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.open(ChecksumFileSystem.java:283)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:356)
at HdfsUrl.read(HdfsUrl.java:29)
at HdfsUrl.main(HdfsUrl.java:58)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kind of exception you are getting suggests thats your application is trying to connect to a datanode that does not have 8020 port open. As per this [documentation](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/08/hadoop-default-ports-quick-reference/)  8020 is the default port **namenode**. I'd suggest adding your hostname and port info. in your **core-site.xml**. something like this:

```
<property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://[namenode]:[port]</value>
</property>
```