# Hadoop Mapreduce - Access Local File System

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, filesystems, hdfs

I have a requirement where in the Map Reduce code should read the local file system in each node. The program will be running on HDFS and I cannot change the FileSystem property for hadoop in xml files for configuration.

I have tried the following solutions, but none gave me results.

Approach 1

```
Configuration config = new Configuration(); 
FileSystem localFileSystem = FileSystem.get(config);
localFileSystem.set("fs.defaultFS", "file:///");
BufferedReader bufferRedaer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(localFileSystem.open(new Path("/user/input/localFile"))));
```

Approach 2

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
LocalFileSystem localFileSystem = FileSystem.getLocal(config);
BufferedReader bufferRedaer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(localFileSystem.open(new Path("/user/input/localFile"))));
```

Approach 3

```
Configuration config = new Configuration(); 
LocalFileSystem localFileSystem = FileSystem.getLocal(config);
localFileSystem.set("fs.defaultFS", "file:///");
BufferedReader bufferRedaer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(localFileSystem.open(new Path("/user/input/localFile"))));
```

Approach 4

```
Configuration config = new Configuration(); 
LocalFileSystem localFileSystem = FileSystem.getLocal(config);
BufferedReader bufferRedaer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(localFileSystem.getRaw().open(new Path("/user/input/localFile"))));
```

This did not work either
[[Reading HDFS and local files in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072543/reading-hdfs-and-local-files-in-java][1])

Each of them gave the error: No such file exists

Error Stack

```
attempt_201406050021_0018_m_000000_2: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File /home/cloudera/sftp/id_rsa does not exist
attempt_201406050021_0018_m_000000_2:   at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:468)
attempt_201406050021_0018_m_000000_2:   at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:380)
attempt_201406050021_0018_m_000000_2:   at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:231)
attempt_201406050021_0018_m_000000_2:   at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:183)
attempt_201406050021_0018_m_000000_2:   at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem.copyFromLocalFile(LocalFileSystem.java:81)
attempt_201406050021_0018_m_000000_2:   at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyFromLocalFile(FileSystem.java:1934)
attempt_201406050021_0018_m_000000_2:   at com.skanda.ecomm.sftp.FTPMapper.configure(FTPMapper.java:91)
```

I am hoping to get a positive solution here. Let me know where I am going wrong.

Main class (Driver class)

```
/*
 * @SFTPClient.java @May 20, 2014
 *
 * 
 */
package com.skanda.ecomm.sftp;

import java.net.URI;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.filecache.DistributedCache;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;

/**
 * 
 * <p>
 * SFTPClient Class
 * </p>
 *
 * @author skanda
 * @version 1.0
 *
 */
public class SFTPClient extends Configured implements Tool {

    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Configuration config = getConf();

        String inputPath = config.get(ApplicationConstants.INPUT_PATH);
        String outputPath = config.get(ApplicationConstants.OUTPUT_PATH);
        String configPath = config.get(ApplicationConstants.CONFIG_PATH);
        int reducers = Integer.parseInt(config.get(ApplicationConstants.REDUCERS));

        if(outputPath == null || inputPath == null || configPath == null) {
            throw new Exception("Usage: \n" + "-D configPath=<configPath> -D inputPath=<inputPath> -D reducers=<reducers" +  
                    "-D outputPath=<path>");
        }

        JobConf conf = new JobConf(SFTPClient.class);
        conf.setJobName("SFTP Injection client");

        DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI(configPath),conf); 

        conf.setMapperClass(FTPMapper.class);
        conf.setReducerClass(FTPReducer.class);

        conf.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        conf.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        conf.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        // configuration should contain reference to your namenode
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
        fs.delete(new Path(outputPath), true); // true stands for recursively, deleting the folder you gave

        conf.setStrings(ApplicationConstants.INPUT_PATH, inputPath);
        conf.setStrings(ApplicationConstants.OUTPUT_PATH, outputPath);

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(inputPath));       
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(outputPath));     

        conf.setNumReduceTasks(reducers);
        conf.setInt(ApplicationConstants.NUNBER_OF_REDUCERS, reducers);

        JobClient.runJob(conf);

        return 0;
    }        

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new SFTPClient(), args);
        System.exit(exitCode);
    }
}
```

Mapper

```
/*
 * @FTPMapper.java  @May 20, 2014
 *
 * 
 */
package com.skanda.ecomm.sftp;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.filecache.DistributedCache;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;

import com.ftp.mapreduce.CommonUtility;
import com.ftp.mapreduce.RetrieveFileNames;
import com.jcraft.jsch.hm.Channel;

/**
 * 
 * <p>
 * FTP Mapper Class
 * </p>
 *
 * @author skanda
 * @version 1.0
 *
 */

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class FTPMapper extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, IntWritable, Text> {

    private URI[] localFiles;       
    private String userName;
    private String hostName;
    private String folderPath;
    private int reducers;
    private byte[] pvtKey;
    private String fileName;
    private String startDate;
    private String endDate;
    private String sshKeyPath;
    private String password;

    public void configure(JobConf job) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        try {
            localFiles = DistributedCache.getCacheFiles(job);

            if (localFiles != null && localFiles.length == 1) {
                Configuration conf = new Configuration();



                FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.get(localFiles[0], conf);
                BufferedReader bufferRedaer=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileSystem.open(new Path(localFiles[0]))));
                properties.load(bufferRedaer);

                userName = properties.getProperty(ApplicationConstants.USER_NAME);
                reducers = job.getInt(ApplicationConstants.NUNBER_OF_REDUCERS, 30);
                hostName = properties.getProperty(ApplicationConstants.SFTP_SERVER_HOST);
                folderPath = properties.getProperty(ApplicationConstants.HOSTFILE_DIRECTORY_PATH);
                fileName = properties.getProperty(ApplicationConstants.FILE_NAME_PATTERN);
                startDate = properties.getProperty(ApplicationConstants.FILE_START_DATE);
                endDate = properties.getProperty(ApplicationConstants.FILE_END_DATE);
                sshKeyPath = properties.getProperty(ApplicationConstants.SSH_KEY_PATH);
                password = properties.getProperty(ApplicationConstants.PASSWORD);

                System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------");
                /*FileSystem fs = FileSystem.getLocal(conf);
                //Path inputPath = fs.makeQualified(new Path(sshKeyPath));
                String inputPath = new Path("file:///home/cloudera/"+sshKeyPath).toUri().getPath();
                fs.copyFromLocalFile(new Path(inputPath), new Path("outputSFTP/idFile") );*/
                try{
                    Configuration conf1 = new Configuration();
                    Path pt = new Path("file:///home/cloudera/.ssh/id_rsa");
                    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get( new URI("file:///home/cloudera/.ssh/id_rsa"), conf);
                    LocalFileSystem localFileSystem = fs.getLocal(conf1);
                    BufferedReader bufferRedaer1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(localFileSystem.open(pt)));

                    String str = null;
                    while ((str = bufferRedaer1.readLine())!= null)
                    {
                        System.out.println("-----------");
                        System.out.println(str);
                    }
                }catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("failed again");
                    String computername=InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
                    System.out.println(computername);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------");



                Configuration config = new Configuration(); 
                config.set("fs.defaultFS", "file:////");
                LocalFileSystem localFileSystem = FileSystem.getLocal(config);
                bufferRedaer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(localFileSystem.open(new Path(sshKeyPath))));

                /*Configuration config = new Configuration();
                //config.set("fs.defaultFS", "file:///home/cloudera/.ssh/id_rsa");
                LocalFileSystem fileSystm = FileSystem.getLocal(config);
                Path path = fileSystm.makeQualified(new Path("/home/cloudera/.ssh/id_rsa"));*/

                //FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, path);

                //bufferRedaer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileSystem.open(path)));

                String key = "";

                try {
                      String line = "";
                      while ((line = bufferRedaer.readLine()) != null) {
                          key += line + "\n";   
                        }
                      pvtKey = key.getBytes();
                } catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    //fileSystem.close();
                    //bufferRedaer.close();
                }       
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<IntWritable, Text> output, Reporter reporter)
        throws IOException {

        List<String> filterFileNamesList = new ArrayList<String>();

        Channel channel = CommonUtility.connectSFTP(userName, hostName, pvtKey);

        Map<String, String> fileNamesMap = CommonUtility.getFileNames(channel, folderPath);

        List<String> filterFileNameList_output = RetrieveFileNames.FILTER_BY_NAME.retrieveFileNames(fileNamesMap, filterFileNamesList, 
                                                            fileName, startDate, endDate);

        for (int i = 0; i < filterFileNameList_output.size(); i++) {
            int keyGroup = i % reducers;
            output.collect(new IntWritable(keyGroup), new Text(filterFileNameList_output.get(i)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure that `ls /home/cloudera/.ssh/id_rsa` in a datanode (remote ssh session in the datanode) is successful?

Answer (score 3):

This code is working for me when program runs on hdfs and my txt file is in this location:

**/home/Rishi/Documents/RishiFile/r.txt**

```
public class HadoopRead {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            Configuration conf = new Configuration();
            Path pt = new Path("/home/Rishi/Documents/RishiFile/r.txt");
            FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get( new URI("/home/Rishi/Documents/RishiFile"), conf);
            LocalFileSystem localFileSystem = fs.getLocal(conf);
            BufferedReader bufferRedaer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(localFileSystem.open(pt)));

            String str = null;
            while ((str = bufferRedaer.readLine())!= null)
            {
                System.out.println("-----------");
                System.out.println(str);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Word Count Example for reading local file on hdfs

my main class

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;


public class FileDriver extends Configured implements Tool {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new FileDriver(), args);
            System.exit(0);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public int run(String[] arg0) throws Exception {

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Path pt = new Path("file:///home/winoria/Documents/Ri/r");

        Job job = new Job(conf, "new Job");
        job.setJarByClass(FileDriver.class);

        job.setMapperClass(FileMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(FileReducer.class);

        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, pt);
        FileSystem.get(job.getConfiguration()).delete(new Path("Output2"), true);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("Output2"));
        job.waitForCompletion(true);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

mapper class :

```
public class FileMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

    protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value,Context context) throws java.io.IOException ,InterruptedException {

        String str[] = value.toString().split(" ");
        for(int i =0; i<str.length;i++){
            context.write(new Text(str[i]), new Text());
        }
    };
}
```

Reducer Class:

```
public class FileReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

    protected void reduce(Text key,Iterable<Text> value,Context context) throws java.io.IOException ,InterruptedException {

        int count=0;
        for (Text text : value) {
            count++;
        }
        context.write(key, new Text(count+""));
    };
}
```

Comment: Rishi, the code you have shared works as a stand alone code. 
However when running on a hadoop cluster, it throws the error file not found.
    attempt_201406050021_0018_m_000000_2: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File /home/cloudera/sftp/id_rsa does not exist
    attempt_201406050021_0018_m_000000_2:  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:468)
    attempt_201406050021_0018_m_000000_2:  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:380)

Comment: @Skandy i am runing this code on a hadoop cluster it wolud not give me any king error

Comment: Hi Rishi, I am trying to run the code in Map Reduce program and this code I have incorporated in the mapper and reducer. 
this is on CDH4. 
Can you please share your Map Reduce code. It would be helpful.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: @Skandy please show your main class and mapper code

Comment: Rishi,I have added the classes you asked in my original question

Comment: @Skandy this my code which read local file and count the word

Comment: @Skandy You probably don't have that file in the nodes running your MapReduce code; thus, you get FileNotFoundExceptions. The code works when you run it locally, because the path does exist locally.

Comment: Rishi , Thanks for the example code. However I want to read the data from "each mapper" and not in the driver class.
My requirement is to read the node specific file and perform certain operation based on it.

@cabad the file exists on all of my local nodes. Can you please assist me with an example code.

Comment: @Skandy are you sure that `ls /home/cloudera/.ssh/id_rsa` in a datanode (remote ssh session in the datanode) is successful?

Comment: @cabad Yes, the ssh is sucessful.
I checked for the same file in all the nodes in my cluster

Comment: @Skandy sorry about the messup, the file that is not found is not in `/home/cloudera/.ssh/id_rsa` it is in `/home/cloudera/sftp/id_rsa` (`sftp` != `.ssh`). Perhaps you meant to use `.ssh` in your path instead of `sftp`?

Comment: @cabad we are both getting confused  because of the ssh concept here.
Let me redefine my expected outcome here.
I want my Mapper and Reducer to read 'their' own local node FS. I know reading from the driver class is possible, and its working for me. 

But please suggest a work around to enable Mapper/Reducers to read node FS.

Comment: @Skandy, there's nothing special to be done. You should be able to read your local FS, but your error message indicates that the file it can't find is located in `/home/cloudera/sftp`.