# Why would you define return value as function parameters in Hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop

At the moment I'm going through the [Hadoop documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.html) about `Mapper` Class

In the signature (*is that the right nomenclature?*), we have to specify what we put into it, and also what comes out:

```
Mapper<KEYIN,VALUEIN,KEYOUT,VALUEOUT>
```

Does that mean we need to define and instantiate these data structures outside of where we call this from?

Comment: you mean like this example on that page? public class TokenCounterMapper 
     extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable> those types must be known by the compiler, but what do you mean have to be initialized before calling the method? You would set the result of the method before running the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the InputFormat and OutputFormat of the specific MapReduce task, yes. It's not the return value, though, it's what's written to the Context output.

This is all configured via the Job class.

The "signature" as you call it, is no different than any other application of Java generics.

For the default TextInputFormat + LineRecordReader, they use LongWritable and Text, for those parameters.

Other formats and Writables are already defined by the Hadoop libraries, if that's your question.

You're welcome to define your own, though

Comment: do you think I would be able to largely reuse the WordCount code if I'm trying to pass is an array of Strings of the form `makePush,1964`, i.e. each record looks like that?

Comment: You would pass a textfile to the mapper, as word count does. Not an array

Comment: I've been trying to process the files in kind of a strange way until now- like this https://gist.github.com/s-matthew-english/5757c6cd01bcb2fa0bca656e9637efac that's why I was thinking to do it as an array. so- that file isn't so useful then?

Comment: You aren't using mapreduce there. You just download the file off of hdfs and operate as you would as if it was located on local filesystem

Comment: yeah but I was thinking it was a prerequiste to map reduce- since for map reduce I'll have to read the files off hdfs- you know what I mean? at the moment I'm trying to meld that file with the wordcount example to make it into a map reduce job

Comment: You don't need a file on HDFS. I've tested MapReduce locally. For example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24076306/hadoop-mapreduce-access-local-file-system