# How to read the file from HDFS using java Scanner class?

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to read one of the files placed in HDFS using the scanner class but I am unable to do so. This is not part of driver code. This code is inside different class and  I am  calling this from mapper code. I have seen one of the SO answers on how to read the file using Buffer Reader but I am trying to do the same using Scanner. I tried directly adding HDFS path in scanner like below but it didn't work.

```
 File fi= new File("hdfs://localhost:9000/InputDataSet/IN/helper.txt");
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fi);  // Reading file
```

Can someone let me know what I am missing here?

Comment: This will  not work... Java File objects cannot read HDFS paths... Your BufferedReader example was from the local filesystem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading HDFS and local files in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072543/reading-hdfs-and-local-files-in-java)