# How to pass configuration file that hosted in HDFS to Spark Application?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, configuration, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I'm working with Spark Structured Streaming. Also, I'm working with `Scala`. I want to pass config file to my spark application. This configuration file hosted in `HDFS`. For example;

**spark_job.conf (HOCON)**

```
spark {
  appName: "",
  master: "",
  shuffle.size: 4 
  etc..
}

kafkaSource {
  servers: "",
  topic: "",
  etc..
}

redisSink {
  host: "",
  port: 999,
  timeout: 2000,
  checkpointLocation: "hdfs location",
  etc..
}
```

How can I pass it to Spark Application? How can I read this file(`hosted HDFS`) in Spark?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072543/reading-hdfs-and-local-files-in-java help?

Comment: I've seen this solution. But I'm looking other ways. Because this way isn't seen good to me. Also, I'm using Scala.

Comment: There's also an equivalent Scala API. If for whatever reason you don't want to do it that way, you should explain why not.

Comment: Because, this solution uses hadoop configuration files. My code have not "hadoop conf" files. Also, I want to pass any "spark conf" to application like appName etc. Thus I can't use spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration. I don't know how can I do this.

Comment: If you don't want to read your data into a Hadoop Configuration object, https://github.com/lightbend/config is a popular generic HOCON configuration reader. You still need to read the file using the Scala HDFS API.

Comment: I'm using typesafe api. I think you are right. The only way is seems this(read file from hdfs in the each worker node) for now.

Comment: It is Serializable, so you can read the config once in the driver and have it passed to the task nodes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can read the HOCON config from HDFS in the following way:

```
import com.typesafe.config.{Config, ConfigFactory}
import java.io.InputStreamReader
import java.net.URI
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration

val hdfs: FileSystem = FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://"), new Configuration())

val reader = new InputStreamReader(hdfs.open(new Path("/path/to/conf/on/hdfs")))

val conf: Config = ConfigFactory.parseReader(reader)
```

You can also pass the URI of your namenode to the `FileSystem.get(new URI("your_uri_here"))` and the code will still read your configuration.

Comment: In the `new Path("/path/to/conf/on/hdfs")`,  should address be the `hdfs://path/to/conf` or just `path/to/conf` ? Also, thank you so much!

Comment: only the path on hdfs without the `hdfs://` prefix. e.g /user/a-better-world/conf/spark_job.conf

Comment: typo in import com.typesafe.config.{Cofig, ConfigFactory} .. should be "Config". This was too small of a change to edit in the post